# How can I get the clientID and redirect URI to access files from onedrive in my angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onedrive

I am developing an angular application. In my application I need files to be accessed from onedrive. I read their articles and found that I need to register an application before accessing WL API's.

I created an application as described in this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn659750.aspx.

I am developing angular application locally so I gave **localhost** or **127.0.0.1** as my redirect URL. But it is throwing the below error when I save the registered application.

"You must enter a valid domain - query strings are not allowed. Length is limited to 248 characters".

What should I specify in the redirect URL if I am developing the application locally? Specifying localhost or 127.0.0.1 in redirect URL is throwing the above error.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you'll want to leave the redirect URL on the application management site blank and follow the steps outlined on https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn631817.aspx. There's a special redirect URL (https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf) that is used to retrieve the access token.  I hope that helps.